# How to fire jQuery on dom ready in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Newbie to angularjs and trying to fire some jQuery on Dom Ready. But it's not working, so looking for a way around this.

Im using an include to pull in a view based on JSON:

```
    <div ng-include="'views/case_builder_wines.html'" onload="loadMe()"></div>
```

And in my controller, tried using this:

```
$scope.loadMe = function() {
    $('input#save-1681006').prop('checked', true);

}
```

But doesnt seem to be working. Also tried this:

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
     $('input#save-1681006').prop('checked', true);
 });
```

But it wont fire, I think because the dom isn't ready. Is there any easy way to get around this?

Comment: Show code of views/case_builder_wines.html

Comment: Could this be abstracted into it's own directive? That way you will have access to the element? It's not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve from the above example.

Comment: Maybe this could interest you: http://jsfiddle.net/JimSangwine/Tzg49/

Answer (score 0):

Given a module `foo`, replace `ng-app` with manual bootstrapping. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
  {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['foo']);
  $('input#save-1681006').prop('checked', true);
  });
```

> Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the angular.js script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState is set to 'complete'.
>
> If you need to have more control over the initialization process, you can use a manual bootstrapping method instead.
>
> During application bootstrap, before Angular goes off creating all services, it configures and instantiates all providers. We call this the configuration phase of the application life-cycle. During this phase, services aren't accessible because they haven't been created yet.
>
> Once the configuration phase is over, interaction with providers is disallowed and the process of creating services starts. We call this part of the application life-cycle the run phase.

**References**

- [AngularJS Developer Guide: Bootstrap - Manual Initialization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization)